# WordPress not showing the latest articles in RSS feed

Tags: rss, feed

I use the FD feedburner plugin to redirect all feeds of my self hosted WP site to Feedburner. That has worked fine until December 2013. Since then the redirection doesn't work anymore. The [feed](http://www.herrenhof.net/feed/) [validates fine](http://feedvalidator.org/check.cgi?url=http://www.herrenhof.net/feed/). The same is true if I subscribe the feed through the Thunderbird RSS reader: posts after 12/2013 are not showing. If I export the posts to a blank WordPress installation, Thunderbird shows all posts in the RSS feed.

I'm totally stuck here. Why would WordPress include posts until December 2013 but not the recent ones? And why does it work when the posts are imported to a new blank installation?

Would be glad for any help. Thank you!

Comment: I am a little lost what is your actual issue here. Link you provide _does_ include recent post. You didn't provide any link for FB version? What exactly is wrong with redirection?

Comment: That's the problem: The recent posts are in the feed, but don't show in Feedburner (http://feeds.feedburner.com/herrenhof/hEdQ) or in Thunderbird RSS reader.

Answer (score 0):

Verify that Feedburner is pulling in the correct URL for your original RSS or Atom feed and then try resyncing your feed in Feedburner under the Troubleshootize tab.

Answer (score -2):

Try the plugin **Better WordPress Google XML Sitemaps** (http://betterwp.net/wordpress-plugins/google-xml-sitemaps/), it is a wonderful sitemap generator for Wordpress.

Comment: This wouldn't solve the problem, would it?

Comment: Why do you think this is relevant in this case? How would generating sitemap affect RSS feeds?